# How to format date to 'yyyy-MM-dd' using Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm building dynamic SOQL query for the search page

I have the following code:

VFP:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Invoice Date">
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MMMM' 'dd', 'yyyy}" label="date"> 
      <apex:param value="{!p.Invoice_Date__c}"  />
</apex:outputText> 
</apex:column>
```

Apex:

My `Invoice_Date__c` is a `date field` in the object

If I execute the following code in Anonymous window I do see the correct format but with my building dynamic SOQL I see the `2017-07-17 00:00:00`

```
Date d = s.Invoice_Date__c;
string dateStr = DateTime.newInstance(d.year(),d.month(),d.day()).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
system.debug('//' + dateStr);
```

Dynamic query building:

```
if (s.Invoice_Date__c != null) {
      Datetime d = s.Invoice_Date__c;
      String dateOutput = d.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
      string invoiceDateFormated = DateTime.newInstance(d.year(),d.month(),d.day()+1).format('yyyy-MM-dd');  
      system.debug('dateOutput: ' + dateOutput);                                       
      query += ' and Invoice_Date__c = '+invoiceDateFormated ; 
}
```

other thing I have noticed that even if I select today's date which is `07/17/2017` but in debug it showing me `07/16/2017` that's why I end-up adding `+1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't do the same thing in both examples:

```
String foo(Date input)
{ // your first example
    return DateTime.newInstance(
        input.year(), input.month(), input.day()
    ).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
}
String bar(Date input)
{ // your second example
    Datetime output = input;
    // Type Coercion  ^^^^^
    return output.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
}
String baz(Date input)
{ // another approach
    return DateTime.newInstance(
        input, Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0)
    ).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
}

system.debug(foo(Date.today()));
system.debug(bar(Date.today()));
system.debug(baz(Date.today()));
```

In your first example, you use `foo`, but in your second, you use `bar`. What you do in `bar` is called **`Type Coercion`** where you assign a `Date` to a `Datetime`. That gives it a `Time` instance of `(0,0,0,0)`, but a `Time Zone` of `GMT`. So you could also fix `bar` by using `formatGmt`:

```
String qux(Date input)
{ // your second example rewritten
    Datetime output = input;
    return output.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd');
    //                  ^^^
}
```

---

You could also think about your original bar as being equivalent to a slight change in `baz`:

```
String quux(Date input)
{
    Datetime output = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(input, Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0));
    // now output is the same as it was in `bar`
    return output.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

You have the `Datetime` in the `GMT` Timezone, so you need to use `formatGmt`:

```
String garply(Date input)
{
    Datetime output = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(input, Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0));
    // now output is the same as it was in `bar`
    return output.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd');
    //                  ^^^
}
```

---

* <sub><sup>[What's after baz?](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2004/09/whats-next-after-foo-bar.html)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 7):

To format a Date object to YYYY-MM-DD, you just need one line:

```
String.valueOf(dateObject);
```

Comment: This gives different results for different users, based on their personal Locale Settings.